# Magento 2 data migration table or view not found

Tags: magento2, data-migration, data-migration-tool

I'm migrating Magento 1.7.2 to Magento 2.3.4 with respect to Magento data migration documentation. However I'm getting below error after post processing.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mgn_' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  mgn_
```

I'm unable to figure out issue, since error comes with prefix alone and no table is mentioned.

> [WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: mgn_inventory_source_item Source: 3311 Destination: 3307
>   [WARNING]: Volume Check failed
>
> [INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: PostProcessing Step]: started
>   92% [=========================>--] Remaining Time: 1 sec In Mysql.php line 110:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mgn_' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mgn_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is reproducible in Magento **2.3.4** only. I have created issue in [github][1] and it has been addressed.

> https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/791